# EEG signal processing

Tags: matlab, eeg

I have an EEG data set downloaded from physionet. I want to play that data into a brain monitoring device like for example BIS monitor or Narcotrend or any other similar brain monitoring device.I use Matlab GUI to visualize the data. Can I send it from a Matlab GUI to any one of the brain monitoring devices with a suitable hardware  in between.Any ideas please I am new to EEG signals.

Comment: is there any reason you cannot use [MATLAB's sound() utility](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sound.html) to play out the data?  you might have to [resample()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html) the EEG data to some soundlike sample rate. if your "soundcard" has a DC-blocking capacitor in its output (and they usually don't need to nowadays), then you might have a problem.  but i think you can get meaningful output where the DC component is not removed with most computers' sound out device.

Comment: Hi robert, What I really want to do is I want to send the historical data set into  different brain monitoring devices and to do a bench marking study .But  I don't have  real patients to do a bench marking. So my GUI should act like a simulator which plays data into the device  say for example it will have DAC in between the GUI and sensor-electrode interface. Sensor surface should think as if the patient is there and it must sense my data I am sending through Matlab.Any ideas please

Comment: okay, so does your computer have a DAC in it's sound output device?  (rhetorical question)  can you use that DAC?  why not?

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume that you want to do online monitoring.

You can always store the coming data from the GUI in a vector in MATLABA.
Then you can run simple code to plot them.

This also depends on the type of measurements you have. If the set is capable on detecting power ranges as well you should have the following readings:

High Alpha, Low Alpha, High Beta, Low Beta, High Gamma, Low Gamma, Delta, Theta, Attention, and Meditation.